# how to get Avg. Session Duration and Bounce Rate in google analytics in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics-api

Im getting page views but how to get rest of the things like

### Avg. Session Duration and Bounce Rate

```
GoogleConnector ga = new GoogleConnector(@"C:\Users\Prashanth\Downloads\NewDemoProject-2590545ddfdfs.p12", "554818524279-g0erg68fvle5unijru@developer.gserviceaccount.com");

var nuberOfPageViews = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196925", new string[] { "ga:pageviews" },
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];

Console.WriteLine(nuberOfPageViews);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what tutorial did you follow to get that code?  or are you writing this yourself?

Comment: i got this code from website @DalmTo

Comment: which website there are a lot of them you know.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 GoogleConnector ga = new GoogleConnector(@"C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\infibeam\NewDemoProject-199399.p12", "554818524279-g0erg68fvl@developer.gserviceaccount.com");

            var PageViews = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:pageviews" },
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];
            var sessionDuration = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:sessionDuration" },
             DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];
            var avgSessionDuration = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:avgSessionDuration" },
           DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];

            var bounceRate = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:bounceRate" },
          DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];

            var sessions = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:sessions" },
     DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];
            var bounces = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:bounces" },
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];
            var hits = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:98196", new string[] { "ga:hits" },
   DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];

   Console.WriteLine("page views : {0}\n Session Duration : {1} \n Avg Session Duration : {2}\n Bounce Rate :{3}\n hits: {4}\n Sessions:{5} ", PageViews , sessionDuration, avgSessionDuration, bounceRate, sessions, bounces, hits, sessions);
            Console.Read();

        }
```